# Como ocultar credenciales en Angular

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-web-api, requests

Desde Angular con NgRx estoy consumiendo una API hecha en C# a la cual se le envía un usuario y contraseña y esta retorna un token de autenticación con encriptado MD5, sin embargo por algún motivo esta contraseña y usuario se muestran en la herramienta del desarrollador apartado Network-Header-Request Payload se muestran las credenciales enviadas como se muestra en la imagen.

[image: request payload]

Se supone que se esta haciendo una encriptación desde el backend, existe la posibilidad de ocultar estas credenciales desde el front Angular?

Comment: Si se está usando https para comunicarse con la API entonces las credenciales están seguras, no es ningún problema que puedan verse desde las herramientas del navegador.

Comment: Entiendo, si claro que se esta utilizando https @Lobos pero no existe una manera de ocultarlas, pasa que para algunos clientes es incomodo porque alguien puede acceder a esta área y tomar las credenciales sin problema.

Comment: El único momento en que alguien puede ver esas credenciales es cuando se hace el login y tiene que estar ahí, junto al usuario, con el inspector de red abierto. Me parece que ya es un escenario bastante exagerado ya que el inspector de red no es para un usuario final.  Partiendo de eso, si una persona mal intencionada tuviera acceso al navegador ni siquiera necesita las credenciales, puede robarse el token de sesión y conectarse desde otro lado. La seguridad está repartida en varios niveles y las acciones del usuario son parte de la seguridad del sistema.

Comment: Respondiendo a tu pregunta: No, no es posible. Algunos programadores aplican algún cifrado, o convierten a base64 las credenciales para que no se entienda su contenido pero es casi igual a mostrarlas como son. Si un atacante las toma igual las envía al servidor y puede iniciar sesión.

Comment: Entiendo Lobos, crei que este tenia manejo al menos por medio del backend, tal vez un jwt o algo asi, lo que no entiendo es porque se muestra eso alli

Comment: Se muestra porque es un herramienta para analizar las peticiones que se están haciendo en esa pestaña del navegador, muy útil para los desarrolladores. Y solo se muestra esa información si la herramienta de análisis se abre antes de hacer la petición, no muestra históricos de peticiones. No hay un motivo real para preocuparse por la seguridad en ese punto.